# `predict` error while doing n-fold cross-validation for my GLM

Tags: r, regression, glm, cross-validation, predict

I am running this function to do n-fold cross-validation. The misclassification rate does not vary over folds, e.g. if I run 10 or 50. I am also getting a warning:

> "Warning message:
>
> 'newdata' had 19 rows but variables found have 189 rows"

If I run the code without being part of a function, it is doing want I want -> e.g. for folds==1, it is pulling out 10%, running the model on 90% of the data, and predicting the other 10%.
Does anyone have any ideas as to why it is not showing variation by variable and the number of folds?

```
library("MASS")  
data(birthwt)
data=birthwt

n.folds=10

jim = function(x,y,n.folds,data){

  for(i in 1:n.folds){
    folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(data)),breaks=n.folds,labels=FALSE)      
    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- data[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- data[-testIndexes, ]
    glm.train <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial, data=trainData)
    predictions=predict(glm.train, newdata =testData, type='response')
    pred.class=ifelse(predictions< 0, 0, 1)
    }

  rate=sum(pred.class!= y) / length(y)
  print(head(rate))
  }

jim(birthwt$smoke, birthwt$low, 10, birthwt)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the predictions should be (<0.5, 0,1).  The function is still not right, but thanks for your observation.

Comment: I want pred.class as a vector that has all of the predictions from each fold.  In this function, I'm just getting 19 back, when it should be 189. Then I produce rate using this vector of length 189.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now making my comments into an answer.

```
jim <- function(x, y, n.folds, data) {   

  pred.class <- numeric(0)  ## initially empty; accumulated later
  for(i in 1:n.folds){
    folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(data)), breaks = n.folds, labels = FALSE)  
    testIndexes <- which(folds == i)  ## no need for `arr.ind = TRUE`
    testData <- data[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- data[-testIndexes, ]
    ## `reformulate` constructs formula from strings. Read `?reformulate`
    glm.train <- glm(reformulate(x, y), family = binomial, data = trainData)
    predictions <- predict(glm.train, newdata = testData, type = 'response')
    ## accumulate the result using `c()`
    ## change `predictions < 0` to `predictions < 0.5` as `type = response`
    pred.class <- c(pred.class, ifelse(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1))
    }

  ## to access a column with string, use `[[]]` not `$`
  rate <- sum(pred.class!= data[[y]]) / length(data[[y]])
  rate  ## or `return(rate)`
  }

jim("smoke", "low", 10, birthwt)
# [1] 0.3121693
```

Remark:

1. No need to put `arr.ind = TRUE` here, although it has no side-effect.
2. There is something wrong with your classification. You set `type = "response"`, then you use `ifelse(predictions < 0, 0, 1)`. Think about it, you always get 1 for `pred.class`.
3. Each iteration of your `for` loop overwrites the `pred.class`. I think you want to accumulate the result. So do `pred.class <- c(pred.class, ifelse(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1))`;
4. Wrong use of `glm` and `predict`. It is wrong to put `$` in model formula. Please read [Predict() - Maybe I'm not understanding it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9028662/4891738). Here, I have changed your function to accept variable names (as a string), and use proper model formula inside `glm`. Note, this change requires to place `y` with `data[[y]]` in `rate = sum(pred.class!= y) / length(y)`.
5. You probably want to return `rate` rather than just printing it to screen. So replace your `print` line by explicit `return(rate)`, or implicit `rate`.
6. You can replace `ifelse(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)` with `as.integer(predictions < 0.5)`, although I did not change it in above.

Comment: Thank you.  The rate should be % of predictions that are not the same as y.  Predictions should be a stack of the predictions from each prediction in the loop.  I see now that each iteration overwrites pred.class.  How can I return predictions and then compute rate?

Comment: Thanks for that.  However, if you input other variables into jim("smoke", "low", 10, birthwt), e.g. "age", "low", or "race" "low", you still get 31%.  Also, if you change n.folds to say 50, you still get 31%.  That is where the issue is.  Something is wrong.

Comment: I see now.  Funny that for folds>10, the rate does not change.  Thank you very much for that.  I do greatly appreciate your time in helping me with this!  Maybe some day I'll be able to contribute!