# Nested lapply with substitute in R

Tags: r, nested, lapply, lm

I've created code to run the lm command multiple times with different variables:

```
DVs <- c('mpg', 'wt')

lapply(DVs, function(x)
  lm(substitute(scale(DV) ~ scale(disp)+scale(qsec), list(DV = as.name(x))), data=mtcars))
```

However, I would like to be able to create a nested loop, to iterate through another variable as well.  The code I have used to attempt that is:

```
DVs <- c('mpg', 'wt')
IVs <- c('disp', 'hp')

    lapply(DVs, function(x) lapply(IVs, function(y)
      lm(substitute(substitute(scale(DV) ~ scale(IV)+scale(qsec), list(DV = as.name(x)), list(IV = as.name(y)), data=mtcars)))))
```

However this leads to an error:

> Error in substitute(scale(DV) ~ scale(IV) + scale(qsec), list(DV =
>   as.name(x)),  :   unused arguments (list(IV = as.name(X[[i]])), data =
>   mtcars)

How can I make this nested loop work?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `reformulate()`, as e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474639/980833).

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Josh O'Brien! This worked:

```
DVs <- c('mpg', 'wt')
IVs <- c('disp', 'hp')

lapply(DVs, function(x) lapply(IVs, function(y) {lm(reformulate(response=x, termlabels=y), data=mtcars)}))
```

I couldn't figure out how to scale my data within the call, but I can just scale my whole dataframe:

```
mtcarsSC <- as.data.frame(scale(mtcars))

DVs <- c('mpg', 'wt')
IVs <- c('disp', 'hp')

lapply(DVs, function(x) lapply(IVs, function(y) {lm(reformulate(response=x, termlabels=y), data=mtcarsSC)}))
```